# Why is the singularity ignored?

Tags: physics, volume, singularity, potential-theory, singular-integrals

In this article "[Reflections on Maxwell’s Treatise](https://pdfs.semanticscholar.org/b395/1ef16ff023237fa3516627c5264fc9fd57bc.pdf)", Section 4.2, it says:

He replaces $\mathbf{m}$ with a volume element of magnetization $\mathbf{M}\ dV$ , integrates over $V$ , and lets the same integral define the magnetic potential inside as well as outside the magnetization to get in Art. $385$ equation $8$ ([of Maxwell's treatise](https://archive.org/details/ATreatiseOnElectricityMagnetism-Volume2/page/n33)):

$\displaystyle \psi_m (\mathbf {r})=\dfrac{1}{4 \pi} \int_V \mathbf{M(r')}.\nabla'  \left(     \dfrac{1}{\left|   \mathbf{r}-\mathbf{r'}  \right|}       \right) dV' \tag{22}$

Why is the singularity in equation $(22)$ being ignored?

Comment: It is not being ignored. It is being integrated over.

Comment: What is meant by "integrating over a singular point"? In case of singular points in the domain of integration, shouldn't we use improper integral? Why is it not used here?

Comment: Also posted (under a different user id?) at https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/464552/why-is-the-singularity-not-taken-into-account

Comment: @LonelyProf: Is there anything illegal about it?

Comment: It's not "illegal", but I believe that it is not generally recommended. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/64068/is-cross-posting-a-question-on-multiple-stack-exchange-sites-permitted-if-the-qu. At least, you should indicate that you are doing this (on both sites) with a link to the other question. Cross-posting generally makes more work for people who might look at your question, unaware that it is has been answered or is being discussed elsewhere.

Comment: thanks... I will do it in future posts